Keyboards and mice dont work on raspberry pi zero when connected via usb hub
I have a USB hub that works with my PC (ubuntu 22.04) but doesn't connect "low power usb devices" (aka both of my keyboards and a mouse) to the Raspberry PI Zero. The hub does connect internet over USB and a camera. And the keyboards and mice work directly.
I've tried powering the Raspberry Pi Zero both via a PC and a 1A USB charger.
lsusb shows:
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0a05:7211 Unknown Manufacturer hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Fundation 2.0 root hub

journalctl -f is showing:
Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 =  00021501
usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 49 using dwc_otg
Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 =  00021501
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a05, idProduct=7211, bcdDevice= 1.00
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 HUB
usb 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
usb 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
dwc_otg_handle_wakeup_detected_intr lxstate = 2
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 50 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 51 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 52 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 53 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 54 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 55 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 56 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 57 using dwc_otg

Raspberry Pi Zero has lastest legacy Bullseye Raspberry OS.

Your question is vague and lacking detail but if you are using OTG you can't use a hub.

@Milliways How do I connect my hub then? Is the problem the USB-microUSB adapter? What other info does the question need?

Your choice is simple; either use OTG or use a hub; the port can do EITHER. If you want networking you really shouldn't have bought a Pi Zero.

@Milliways But the hub with only keyboard and mouse is not working.

There is little point in commenting. You have provided no details of what is connected or how the Pi is configured.

Use a USB hub that has its own dedicated power supply.

@liaifat85 I can add a power supply to my hub, will that work? Why is it not working now?

Some USB hubs come with a power adapter. You may need to buy one of those.

@liaifat85 I tried powering the hub, with a USB-A USB-A cable, connected to the computer, the pi zero turns on, but the keyboard and mouse are not on. The hub is this one
